# Is N a normal subgroup of Z(G)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose p is a prime number, G is a group of order $p^4$ and $N$ is it’s normal subgroup, such that $|N|=p$ and $\frac{G}{N}$ is abelian. Is $N$ always a normal subgroup of $Z(G)$?

I failed both to prove this statement and to find any counterexample.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For any nontrivial normal  subgroup $N$ of any finite $p$-group $G$, we have $N \cap Z(G) \ne 1$, and so $|N|=p \Rightarrow N \le Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_G(N)$ - centralizer of $N$ in $G$ and $|G:C_G(N)| = p^a$

Then $G/C_G(N) \cong A \le Aut(N)$

$p$ is prime, so $|Aut(N)| = p-1$

Hence $p^a | (p-1)$, which is only possible for $a=0$

Therefore $C_G(N) = G$ and $N \le Z(G)$